# questions about understanding the Cantor set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> **2.44 The Cantor set** The set which we are now going to construct shows
> that there exist perfect sets in R^1 which contain no segment.
> Let $E_0$ be the interval [0, 1]. Remove the segment$({1 \over 3 },{2 \over 3 })$ and let $E_1$ be
> the union of the intervals $[0,{1 \over 3 }]$,$[{2 \over 3 },1]$.
> Remove the middle thirds of these intervals, and let E2 be the union of the
> intervals
> $[0,{1 \over 9 }]$,$[{2 \over 9 },{3 \over 9 }]$,$[{6 \over 9 },{7 \over 9 }]$,$[{8 \over 9 },1]$
> Continuing in this way, we obtain a sequence of compact sets $E_n$,such that
> (a)$E_1 \supset E_2 \supset E_3 \supset......$
> (b) $E_n$ is the union of $2^n$ intervals, each of length $3^{-n}$
> The set $P=\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} E_{n}$ is called the  Cantor set

$P=\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} E_{n}$ essentially means that$P=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}E_n$, where for a fixed positive integer n, $E_n$ contains intervals, right? However, as n tends to infinity, the lengths of those intervals will approach zero. Can I understand that these intervals then become  points? And the distances between these points also tend to infinitesimal, so Rudin's proof goes as follows:

> To show that P is perfect, it is enough to show that P contains no isolated
> point. Let$x \in p$, and let S be any segment containing x. Let $I_n$ be that interval
> of $E_n$ which contains x. Choose n large enough, so that $I_n \subset S$. Let $x_n$ be an
> endpoint of $I_n$ , such that $x_n\neq x$.
> It follows from the construction of P that$x_n \in p$. Hence x is a limit point
> of P, and P is perfect

Rudin pointed out that x is a limit point of P because as n approaches infinity, for any neighborhood of x, there exists a corresponding $x_n$ in the neighborhood of x. This is because, according to the construction of the set P, the endpoints of the intervals $I_n$ are not discarded. In other words, for any $x_n$ that belongs to $I_n$ and is an endpoint of $I_n$, $x_n$ also belongs to set P. Additionally, as the length of the interval $I_n$ tends to infinitesimal when n approaches infinity, the distance between x and $x_n$ also tends to infinitesimal. This implies that for any neighborhood of x, there will always be an  $x_n$ in the sequence that belongs to set P and lies within the neighborhood of x. Therefore, x is referred to as a limit point of set P.

Is there any issue with my understanding above?

Comment: The proof you cite sounds strange to me. "Let $S$ be any segment containing $x$"... what is "a segment", and how do we know such a segment exists?

Comment: Key issues with Cantor sets to remember: between any two points in $P$, there is at least one interval removed at some stage; and some points in $P$ such as $\frac 13$ are interval end-points at some stage while a majority of points in $P$ (in a cardinality sense) such as $\frac14$ are never interval end-points. If you can understand why neither $\frac13$ nor $\frac14$ are isolated, then you can probably understand the proof.

Comment: You assume $x\in P$ and then say $x\in P$ by construction. Do you mean $x_n\in P$ by construction?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur yes,you are right.

Comment: A segment is exactly an open set like (a, b).Let S be any segment containing x, where S is the open set (a, b) (a, b ∈ R),and a<x<b"@5xum